# Problem in passing data values between classes through delegation object c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I just want to transfer data from MyCoolViewController to firstViewController.

I have a problem with trasferring data from MyCoolViewController class to firstViewController. here is my code

```
MyCoolViewController.h// a class where data send from

@protocol MyCoolViewDelegate;

@interface MyCoolViewController : UIViewController  {


id <MyCoolViewDelegate> delegate;//
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;//


@end
@protocol MyCoolViewDelegate <NSObject>//

-(void)sendAStringToAnotherView:(NSString*)string;
@end

MyCoolViewController.m

-(void)viewDidLoad{
```

label.text=townName;

```
[delegate sendAStringToAnotherView:townName];//problem is here
}




firstViewController.m  //a class where data sent
-(void)viewDidLoad{

MyCoolViewController *myViewControllerPointer=[[MyCoolViewController alloc] init];
myViewControllerPointer.delegate = self;//
}

-(void)sendAStringToAnotherView:(NSString*)string
{
//displays the string as console output
NSLog(@"plzzzzzz show data%@",string);
}
```

it nothing. Please help

Comment: It seems there is no format specifier for string in `NSLog`.

Comment: No that is not issue. i edited that. check my question. but thing is this method is not get called

Comment: @EmptyStack plz help me im stuck on this problem for 3 days. n i have to submit my project

Comment: Change the NSString to the type you want to pass in the protocol definition -(void)sendAStringToAnotherView:(NSString*)string; and the delegate: -(void)sendAStringToAnotherView:(NSString*)string

Comment: @CocoaFu i just want to pass Label1.text=townName; So townName contains name of the town. So this is string object. What should be the type of it. Do i have to allocate something anywhere. but i have already did this for townName string. allocated it n retained it in CoolViewController

Comment: I tried like [delegate sendAStringToAnotherView:(NSString *)nameTown]; but it shows null. This is the last thing i want to do with it.plz suggest

Comment: Mr CocoaFu Please help me coz this is the ultimate thing i want to do.

Comment: @CocoaFu i tried to pass object as well. but it still shows null. i'll be very thankful to you if u sugggest me something. im stuck on this for 4 days. plz help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue with the sample code:

```
NSLog(@"plzzzzzz show data",string);
```

should be:

```
NSLog(@"plzzzzzz show data: %@", string);
```

What is missing is ever loading `MyCoolViewController`.  Just creating it is not enough.  There is going to have to be a similarly named nib or a loadView method.

You can force loading (for testing only) in `firstViewController viewDidLoad` with something like this:

```
[[self.view addSubview:self.myViewControllerPointer.view];
```

2011-08-28 12:32:06.410 TestVC[25700:f203] plzzzzzz show data: this is a string

Comment: No but -(void)sendAStringToAnotherView:(NSString*)string
{
//displays the string as console output
NSLog(@"plzzzzzz show data%@",string); this method is not get called. it is not called in view did load. how can i do that
}

Comment: Please help me im stuck on this for 3 days

Comment: Thanku so much it is working now, God Bless. I  was stuck on this for 3 long days.

Comment: Now if i want to pass object value instead of string. like in MyCoolViewController, 
      [delegate sendAStringToAnotherView:@"%@",name]; It shows error where name is string object containing name of the city.